# Airflow/Cloud Composer execute custom logic when DAG run is killed

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm currently working on a custom sensor operator that launches a job in a remote server and periodically polls for its status. In some cases I may need to cancel/delete this DAG run programmatically with another program. Since the actual job is executed remotely, I want to be able to shut down the remote job before the DAG run is canceled/deleted. Since only the operator has the details of the remote job, I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger some custom logic to shut down the remote job right before the DAG run is going to be canceled/deleted?

Here is a summarized version of my operator code:

```
class JobOperator(base_sensor_operator.BaseSensorOperator):
    def poke(self, context: Any) -> bool:
    if !self._job_started:
        self._job_info = LaunchJob(self._job_config)
    else:
        status = PollJob(self._job_info)
        if status == "SUCCESS":
            # some logic.
        else:
            # some logic.
```

I'm not sure if Airflow has such a trigger to execute some logic before DAG run deletion. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `on_failure_callback` ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html)). I'm assuming you're marking the dag failed using the rest api remotely? I'm not sure if that will trigger a callback. The docs are not clear - it says task changes set by the UI will not trigger a callback but if you mark the dag as failed using the UI the callback is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It can trigger a failure callback if instead of deleting the dag run I modify its state to be failed. I think it will work for now.